# R - Función IF anidada?

Tags: r, condiciones, rstudio

Les escribo para ver si alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente problema que tengo. Me encuentro haciendo un curso de R y nos han dado para hacer un ejercicio en donde todo parecería indicar que debo utilizar la función IF, aunque no sé como hacerlo.

En particular, estamos trabajando con un dataframe (df) que contiene información sobre personas con problemas de sueño. De este modo, tenemos 2 variables que indican cuantas horas han dormido los individuos junto con 3 variables más en donde podemos ver que terapia se le aplico. Para ser más claro, las columnas del df serían las siguientes:

Persona    Hs 1era Noche     Hs. 2da noche     Terapia 1     Terapia 2   Terapia3

1            6                  8               0              1           1

En este caso, tendríamos que la persona durmió 6 horas la primera noche, 8 horas la segunda noche y se le administro la terapia 2 y la 3.

Ahora bien, lo que se nos pide en el ejercicio es construir una nueva variable que resuma el tipo de terapia que se le administro al individuo, de modo tal que:

0 = No se le administro ninguna terapia
1 = Se le administro solo la terapia 1.
...
...

Y así sucesivamente.

Entiendo que lo único que debería hacer es trabajar con una función IF (como la de EXCEL) para que R verifique si se cumple la condición Terapia 1 = 0 ^ Terapia 2 = 0 ^ Terapia 3 = 0, entonces que arroje el valor 0, de lo contrario que continue probando.

Espero que alguien me puede ayudar! Gracias!!

Si, no hay problema. Acá les envío una captura de imagen. Me está volviendo loco R, gracias!

[image: Captura de imagen DF]

La idea sería crear una nueva variable que resuma el tipo de terapia que recibió cada paciente, de modo que la nueva variable asuma los siguientes valores:

0 = No recibió ninguna terapia
1 = Sólo recibió la terapia 1

Y así sucesivamente.

Muchas gracias!

---

Ruben, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responderme y ayudarme. Lamentablemente, en realidad necesitaría conocer qué tipo de terapia recibió el paciente. Para ello, entiendo que habría que crear una nueva variable que tome los siguientes valores:

Variable: Tipo de terapia (T)

T = 0, en caso que no haya recibido terapia alguna.

T = 1, en caso de que sólo haya recibido la terapia 1

T = 2, en caso de que sólo haya recibido la terapia 2

T = 4, en caso de que haya recibido la terapia 1 y la terapia 2.

Y así sucesivamente.

En cualquier caso, muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme Ruben.

Comment: Hola Johnny para poderte dar una respuesta mas adecuada nos podrías compartir un ejemplo de tu data frame

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo que buscas es una variable T que tome un valor distinto por cada combinación de 0 y 1 en 3 lugares, desde (0,0,0) a (1,1,1). Hay 2^3 = 8 combinaciones posibles y T tomará valores de 0 a 7. Ahora, todas las combinaciones pueden representarse por una matriz:

```
#Creamos un data frame de ejemplo 
set.seed(6652) # para que sea reproducible los resultados del ejemplo
suenio_ejem<-data.frame(clave=seq(1,100,1),
                        PrimerNoche=abs(rnorm(100,5,3)),
                        SegundaNoche=abs(rnorm(100,6,3)),
                        Sexo=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),
                        Edad=round(abs(rnorm(100,30,5))),
                        Terapia1=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),
                        Terapia2=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),
                        Terapia3=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE))
> combin <- as.matrix(expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1))
> combin
     Var1 Var2 Var3
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1
[6,]    1    0    1
[7,]    0    1    1
[8,]    1    1    1
```

En este caso se deb tener en cuenta las posiciones (el tipo de terapia) `c(1,2,3)` de modo que (1,0,0) no es lo mismo que (0,1,0) y por lo tanto no se puede simplemente sumar las columnas para obtener T porque se pierde esa información. Voy a ordenar la matriz invirtiendo las filas 4 y 5 para dar

```
combin[,5:4] <- combin[,4:5]
> combin
     Var1 Var2 Var3
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1
[5,]    1    1    0
[6,]    1    0    1
[7,]    0    1    1
[8,]    1    1    1
```

entonces lo que puedo hacer con las tres columnas de las terapias`suenio_ejem[,c("Terapia1","Terapia2","Terapia3")]` es recorrer sus filas y ver en que fila de `combin` hay una coincidencia, eso me da un numero (de 1 a 8) al que puedo restar 1 y obtener el valor de T. Pero como estamos en R no nos gustan los ciclos, vamos a generar caracteres, colapsando las tres columnas de `combin` para obtener un vector de 8 elementos carácter:

```
posiciones <- paste0(combin[,1], combin[,2], combin[,3]) 
posiciones
[1] "000" "100" "010" "001" "110" "101" "011" "111"
# las posiciones - 1 dan los valores posibles de T
# ahora colapso las columnas de las tres terapias y me va a dar uno de los 
# elementos del vector posiciones, para saber cuál uso la función match()
# y esto menos 1 da T:
terapias <- paste0(suenio_ejem[,6], suenio_ejem[,7], suenio_ejem[,8])
suenio_ejem[["T"]] <- match(terapias, posiciones) - 1  
# las 10 primeras columanas
> suenio_ejem[1:10, ]
   clave PrimerNoche SegundaNoche Sexo Edad Terapia1 Terapia2 Terapia3 T
1      1    7.308429     1.659779    1   25        0        0        0 0
2      2    1.723616     7.456470    1   40        1        1        0 4
3      3    4.311716     1.912279    1   36        1        1        0 4
4      4    6.665860     6.127877    1   26        0        0        1 3
5      5    7.133454     4.626898    0   19        1        1        0 4
6      6    8.195977     5.265413    1   34        1        1        1 7
7      7    5.750944     6.713412    1   38        0        1        0 2
8      8    2.027105     7.371320    0   20        0        0        0 0
9      9    9.575251     9.556712    1   28        1        1        1 7
10    10    5.273827     6.523923    1   31        0        0        0 0
```

Hay otra forma, que es multiplicar matricialmente la matriz de las terapias por el vector de posiciones c(1,2,3). Acá el problema es que

```
combin%*% 1:3
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    1
[3,]    2
[4,]    3
[5,]    3
[6,]    4
[7,]    5
[8,]    6
```

el vector fila 1,1,0 (1+2 = 3) da lo mismo que el vector (0,0,1). Tengo que distinguir entre las filas que tienen un solo 1 y las filas que tienen más de un 1. Entonces puedo hacer eso con `rowSums()` y consultar cuales da mayor a 1 y cambiando a numerico:

```
as.numeric(rowSums(combin) > 1)
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
# esto sumado al producto matricial da lo que necesito
> combin%*%1:3 + as.numeric(rowSums(combin) > 1) 
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    1
[3,]    2
[4,]    3
[5,]    4
[6,]    5
[7,]    6
[8,]    7
```

Ahora vamos a los datos

```
suenio_ejem[["T_matriz"]] <- (as.matrix(suenio_ejem[,6:8]) %*% c(1,2,3)) 
                            + as.numeric(rowSums(suenio_ejem[,6:8]) > 1)
> suenio_ejem[1:10,]
   clave PrimerNoche SegundaNoche Sexo Edad Terapia1 Terapia2 Terapia3 T T_matriz
1      1    7.308429     1.659779    1   25        0        0        0 0        0
2      2    1.723616     7.456470    1   40        1        1        0 4        4
3      3    4.311716     1.912279    1   36        1        1        0 4        4
4      4    6.665860     6.127877    1   26        0        0        1 3        3
5      5    7.133454     4.626898    0   19        1        1        0 4        4
6      6    8.195977     5.265413    1   34        1        1        1 7        7
7      7    5.750944     6.713412    1   38        0        1        0 2        2
8      8    2.027105     7.371320    0   20        0        0        0 0        0
9      9    9.575251     9.556712    1   28        1        1        1 7        7
10    10    5.273827     6.523923    1   31        0        0        0 0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizaremos en este caso una función muy similar a if de excel como mencionas
 llamada case_when que viene en la libraria de dplyr , lo cual derivado de las 
 condicionales le asigna un valor

```
#Creamos un data frame de ejemplo 
suenio_ejem<-data.frame(clave=seq(1,100,1),
                    PrimerNoche=abs(rnorm(100,5,3)),
                    SegundaNoche=abs(rnorm(100,6,3)),
                    Sexo=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),
                    Edad=round(abs(rnorm(100,30,5))),
                    Terapia1=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),
                    Terapia2=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),
                    Terapia3=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE))



 #utilizando la library
 suenio_ejem_s<-suenio_ejem %>% 
            mutate(Terapias=case_when(Terapia1==0 & Terapia2==0 Terapia3==0~"T0",
                                     Terapia1==1 & Terapia2==0 & Terapia3==0~"T1",
                                     Terapia1==1 & Terapia2==1 & Terapia3==0~"T2",
                                     Terapia1==1 & Terapia2==1 & Terapia3==1~"T3",
                                     Terapia1==1 & Terapia2==0 & Terapia3==1~"T4",
                                     Terapia1==0 & Terapia2==1 & Terapia3==0~"T5",
                                     Terapia1==0 & Terapia2==1 & Terapia3==1~"T6",
                                     Terapia1==0 & Terapia2==0 & Terapia3==1~"T7"))   


  tail(suenio_ejem_s,5)



  clave PrimerNoche SegundaNoche Sexo Edad Terapia1 Terapia2 Terapia3 Terapias 
   96    2.099250     9.468098    1   34        0        0        0    T0
   97    5.944181     5.687711    0   27        1        0        1    T4
   98    1.350364     9.218964    1   28        1        1        1    T3
   99    5.188188     6.989557    0   30        0        0        1    T7
  100    5.175650     6.718872    0   34        1        0        1    T4
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruben, Marcelo,

Muchísimas gracias por los aportes y las ideas. Probé ambas alternativas y funcionaron perfecto. La verdad recién me estoy adentrando en el mundo de R y todo me resulta bastante cuesta arriba, pero con paciencia va saliendo todo por suerte.

Otra persona me había sugerido probar con una función llamada ifelse, la cual también funcionó. En particular, en primer lugar, me sugirió guardar cada condición en una variable nueva:

x <- Insomnio_2$Terapia1 == 0  &  Insomnio_2$Terapia2 == 0  $ Insominio_2$Terapia3 == 0

........................
........................
........................

Así, debería escribir 8 condiciones en total, de modo que se reflejen todas las combinaciones de terapia posible.

Finalmente, me propuso crear una nueva variable en el dataframe anidando ifelse:

tipo_de_terapia <- ifelse(x, 0, ifelse(x1, 1, ifelse(.....))

En fin, por suerte funcionaron todas las alternativas. Nuevamente muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo para ayudarme.

Saludos!!